# powershell sendkeys with $ not working correct

Tags: powershell

powershell send keys with $ not working correct here is the code

when i put the password with $ it types back as variable

```
$enter_password = Read-Host "Enter Your Password" -AsSecureString

$password = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($enter_password))


$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;

Sleep 3

$wshell.SendKeys($password) 

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("$password")
```

exemple

> password 1q2w3e$R%T^Y
>
> i get 1q2w3e$R

how can i fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to escape special characters:

```
$enter_password = Read-Host "Enter Your Password" -AsSecureString

$password = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($enter_password))


$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.Run("notepad")
$wshell.AppActivate("notepad")
Sleep 3
$password = $password.Replace('%', '{%}').Replace('^','{^}')


$wshell.SendKeys("$password") 
write-host $password
```

Comment: It works with $ but won’t work with ()-+=

Answer (score 0):

In case the input has brackets, clean up the text using the following

```
$cleanString = ""
$string.toCharArray() | foreach {
    if ($_ -in $string){
    $cleanString = $cleanString + "{" + $_ + "}"
}
else{
    $cleanString = $cleanString + $_
    }
}
```

If any character is a keyword, escape it with brackets